# Upgrade to SSD or add memory (or both)

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Dynabook T552/58HK laptop running Windows 10.

I use it for software development - mostly using Android Studio. I continually run into 100% disk usage which seriously slows down the computer, sometimes bringing it to a complete stop.

Also, many times my memory usage shows as 7.9Gb (out of 8).

So, do I replace my HDD with an SSD or do I add more memory - or both?
If I have to choose, which will result in the better improvement?

Also, how do I find exactly which SSD and/or memory cards are compatible with my computer?

I asked this on "Hard Recommendations" but it got deleted as "Off Topic".

Comment: @harrymc is correct, the question is off topic as it is opinion based and asking for shopping recommendations.  However, to answer the question: do both.  A good place to start for both is crucial.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking - hardware recommendations are off topic here too.  It would be interesting to see why the hardware recommendations SE deleted your hardware recommendation request - but their SE, their rules I guess..

My personal recommendation would be to upgrade both.  However, if your budget only allows for disk **OR** memory, I would recommend you change the disk for a solid state one.

A computer is (generally speaking) only as fast as its slowest component.

In your case, it sounds very much like you're using 100% of your memory and still have a demand for further memory that cannot be fulfilled.  This will result in the disk being used to page data in and out of memory to fulfill this demand.  Since a spinning disk is slower than RAM, this will be a slower operation.

Installation of a solid state disk will both speed up any paging that happens (due to the slowest component now being a lot faster) and will also generally speed up your machine all round.

If you use your machine in other scenarios where you don't have 100% RAM demand (web browsing when you're not doing android dev for example) - a solid state disk will speed up your machine here as well, whereas additional memory may not provide as much of a benefit to you.

Others may well disagree with this and say that since your primary concern is an over-demand of memory, then memory is what you should get - but I am trying to take a "bigger picture" view and assume that (like most people) your machine is not just a single use device.

As for deciding which type, size etc to buy:

- **Type, connection etc** - you can get this by looking up your
  PC/motherboard/RAID controller model number and finding out which
  connector type it uses (most likely SATA)
- **Size** - Take a look at what you have now, scale up or down depending
  on how you think your needs will change
- **Speed** - the quicker, the better.  Go with the highest that your budget will allow

Hope this helps

Comment: I forgot to come back and post the outcome. In the end I scraped together enough money for both. Best money spent. It's not just like having a new computer it is super-fast. Much faster than it ever was. I was lucky if I could open 2 Android Studio windows in the past. Now I can open 7 without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is definitely RAM-starved. It begins paging like crazy, which will always result in degraded performance. It may be better with an SSD, but it won't be a smooth experience. RAM upgrade would definitely be recommended. It's hard to say how much you need, but 16 GB should probably be fine. Two 8 GB sticks are preferred over one 16 GB, because they will give you extra performance by enabling dual channel.

After the RAM upgrade system should stop paging and the SSD upgrade may not be necessary. It would improve your experience, though - SSDs don't only speed up file operations, but also make computer feel more snappy thanks to quick and constant data access times.